# Programaticly fill and submit form Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular4-forms

I have following problem: I need to  auto fill form and immediately submitted to some url with post method. 
this is Component .ts and html example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Renderer  } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { PayModel } from './shared/pay.model';
import { PayService } from './shared/pay.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'cp-pay',
    templateUrl: './pay.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./pay.component.css']
})
export class PayComponent implements OnInit {

    model: PayModel;
    cardProcessingId: number;

    constructor(
        private payService: PayService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private renderer: Renderer

    ) {
        this.cardProcessingId = route.snapshot.params["processingid"];
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.model = new PayModel();
        this.getProcessing();

    }

    getProcessing() {
        this.payService.getProcessing(this.cardProcessingId).subscribe(
            res => {
               this.model.fname = res.fname;
               this.model.lname = res.lname;
               this.model.age = res.age;
               }
                err => {
                console.log('getProcessing Error')
            },
            () => {
                let form: HTMLFormElement = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('payform');
                
                form.submit();
            }
        );
  }
}
```

```html
<form ngNoForm id="payform" action="https://localhost:44300/api/pay/test" target="_blank" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="merchant" value="{{model.fname}}" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" value="{{model.lame}}" />
        <input type="text" name="age" value="{{model.age}}" />
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I just want raw html form to be posted to url, that's all, but when code hits form.submit() it posts null values only. I tried to simulate submit button click but it does not work either. I wonder is that kind of thing even possible? It seems to me that form gets submitted before the form is filled. Pls help

Comment: is the form meant to be auto-submitted every time, or can it be sent by user too? If first case, why not post directly to the url with your values as post data? If second case, is the form sent properly when values are entered manually?

Comment: It's meant to be auto submitted every time, users should not even see what's inside it the inputs will be hidden in future

Comment: In that case i would recommend sending directly the request instead of using a form, you can start by looking at [this part of the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)

Comment: yes I know I can do that, but I really need to use form :) its a complicated story :) but I have to

Comment: then, if you make it appear on a page and fill it manually, are the values sent correctly?

Comment: if I fill the form manually and press submit it is sent correctly.

Comment: i'm heading to a busy task and won't be available some hours, next steps would be to `console.log` some vars such as `HTMLFormElement` to verify all has good values, and maybe let the form visible with a timeout between filling the form and submit, to check that it's filled allright..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! I have found a workaround. First things first: the problem was that form submit was happening before the html was populated with values and data posted was empty (null). I didn't know that with Angular could force html to be populated with values pretty much whenever u want using ApplicationRef module. All you need to do is to import module, create ApplicationRef  instance and call it's method .tick() whenever you want to html values to be filled. My code should be like this now:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    import { PayModel } from './shared/pay.model';
    import { PayService } from './shared/pay.service';
    @Component({
        selector: 'cp-pay',
        templateUrl: './pay.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./pay.component.css']
    })
    export class PayComponent implements OnInit {

        model: PayModel;
        cardProcessingId: number;

        constructor(
            private payService: PayService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private appRef: ApplicationRef

        ) {
            this.cardProcessingId = route.snapshot.params["processingid"];
        }
        ngOnInit() {
            this.model = new PayModel();
            this.getProcessing();

        }

        getProcessing() {
            this.payService.getProcessing(this.cardProcessingId).subscribe(
                res => {
                   this.model.fname = res.fname;
                   this.model.lname = res.lname;
                   this.model.age = res.age;
                   appRef.tick(); // to immediately force html value fill
                   }
                    err => {
                    console.log('getProcessing Error')
                },
                () => {
                    let form: HTMLFormElement = document.getElementById('payform');

                    form.submit();
                }
            );
      }
    }
```

On Html side ngNoForm not needed in form tag.